# Meaning of weights in output of glm (logistic regression) - vector of weights

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I asked the question previously as a guest, and stackexchange won't let me edit or respond now that I confirmed my account:

[Understanding output of R glm (logistic regression) prediction - vector of weights](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578368/understanding-output-of-r-glm-logistic-regression-prediction-vector-of-weigh?newreg=5a24905658a24366b44c20483411b5d5)

I got a response there referring to the "working" weights, but those are not what I am talking about (unless I am even more confused than I previously thought).  Rather, I am referring to this line in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/glm):

"'weights' extracts a vector of weights, one for each case in the fit (after subsetting and na.action)."

I am curious, how are these weights calculated?  How are they related to the probability assigned to each sample?  To be very clear, for every sample in the data set used in the fit, I get "weight" and "fitted.value" and I am trying to understand what the former means and how to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

You may be even more confused than you previously thought.

The `weights` function, extracts one of two types of weights, specified by the `type` argument.  With `type="prior"` (the default) it extracts the numbers that you supplied as the `weights=` argument to `glm`.  With `type="working"` it extracts the working weights.

Comment: Thanks for your response! There are 3 instances mentioned in the documentation: "an optional vector of ‘prior weights’ to be used in the fitting process. Should be NULL or a numeric vector."  "weights extracts a vector of weights, one for each case in the fit (after subsetting and na.action)". "weights - the working weights, that is the weights in the final iteration of the IWLS fit." I am talking about the "weights extracts a vector of weights, one for each case in the fit (after subsetting and na.action)." I could definitely use clarification.  The vector is as long as the data.

Comment: The first of those is documenting the `weights=` argument for supplying weights to `glm` (these are the "prior weights"). The second is documenting the `weights()` function, which I covered. The third is documenting the `$weights` component of the glm object, which contains the working weights.